# How to create a HTML input that only accepts 4 digit numeric input that is between 0000-2399

Tags: html, input

I want to create an html input that takes in a 4 digit input that is between 0000 and 2399 (military time).

The problem is that 0000 is equal to 0 meaning that anything lower than 1000 will become less than 4 digits. I want to maintain the military time format.
I have tried `pattern = "[0-9]{4}"` but that only applies for `input type = "text"` and I cannot do a `min` or a `max` for that input type.

Here are my failed attempts using both `pattern` and `min max`:

```
<input type = "number" name = "military_time" pattern= "[0-9]{4}" min = "0000" max = "2399">

<input type = "number" name = "military_time" min = "0000" max = "2399">

<input type = "number" name = "military_time" pattern= "[0-9]{4}" min = "0000" max = "2399">
```

I have a feeling the answer requires Javascript, but if there is another solution that only requires html (or Coldfusion) that will be preferred.

Comment: Let me give another way that is of minimal usefulness: `<input type="time" name="military_time" min="00:00" max="23:99">`

Answer (score 1):

To limit input to the 24 hour clock you should use a pattern like

```
pattern="([01][0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9]"
```

This will take care of the fact that *not all digits* are allowed in the four positions.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would use the pattern attribute, as a regular expression, like so:

```
 <input type="text" name="time_24" pattern="[00-23]{2}:[00-59]{2}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1"> 
 <input type="text"  name="pincode" maxlength="4"  id="pin" pattern="\d{4}" required/>
 <input type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: I like the SO fiddle you supplied, but your pattern needs some tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

**[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/cdkqpja3/)**

Try this way may be its help for you

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" name="quantity" min="0000" max="2399">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```